# context.params.id gives error in nextjs. cannot define property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, next.js

I trying to fetch data from a json file(response.json), which is running in localhost:8000/response.json.
Here is my code in pages/test.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import _ from "lodash"

// components

import Navbar from "components/Navbars/AuthNavbar.js";
import Footer from "components/Footers/Footer.js";

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/response.json");
  const data = await res.json();

  const paths = data.data.map((gallery) => {
    return {
      params: { id: gallery.id },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  
  const id = context.params.id;
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/response1.json");
  const data = await res.json();
  
  const thumbnail_ = data.data.filter(parentid => parentid.parent_id == id)
  return {
    props: { image_data: thumbnail_ },
  };
  
};


export default function Landing({ image_data }) {
    console.log(image_data)
    return (
    <div>
    </div>
);
}
```

My response.json file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 1,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/434090/pexels-photo-434090.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Animals",
            "title": "Animals"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 2,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/5703286/pexels-photo-5703286.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Birds",
            "title": "Birds"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 3,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3802510/pexels-photo-3802510.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Car",
            "title": "Cars"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 4,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/40904/bmw-k-1300-metallic-motorcycle-40904.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Bikes",
            "title": "Bikes"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 5,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3220368/pexels-photo-3220368.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Fishes",
            "title": "Fishes"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 6,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1040880/pexels-photo-1040880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Actors",
            "title": "Actors"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 7,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6896193/pexels-photo-6896193.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Actresses",
            "title": "Actresses"
        },
        {
            "collection": null,
            "id": 8,
            "image_thumbanil": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/37859/sailing-ship-vessel-boat-sea-37859.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
            "images_id": null,
            "item": null,
            "name": "Ships",
            "title": "Ships"
        }
    ]
}
```

The error is get is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
[image: error display in browser]

My goal is to display images with parent_id = 1, I want that id to increment by one for every time the program runs. For eg.) when I run the next app, I want to get display items with parent_id = 1 and then 2 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

If you use params from `getStaticProps` in a page your js file must be named aka `[id].js`.

Doc [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation).

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks, Emmanuel, it worked now.